# Create div inside another dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to dynamically create a div inside another using jquery, but it does not show up. My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#well_show').click(function(){
        $("#gen_div").empty(); //empty previous generated divs if any
        $("#gen_div").append("<div id='well'></div>"); //create new div
        $('#well').css("height","500px","width","500px","background-color","red"); 
    }); 
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.css` syntax is incorrect, you should pass in an object ([see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) for valid overloads). As it stands, you're accessing the `css( propertyName, value )` overload and so only the `height` property is being applied.

```
$("#well").css({
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    backgroundColor: "red"
});
```

I've cleaned up your code somewhat (replaced document.ready and chained the `empty` and `append` calls:

```
$(function() {
    $('#well_show').click(function(){
        $("#gen_div").empty().append("<div id='well'></div>"); //create new div
        $("#well").css({
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            backgroundColor: "red"
        });
    }); 
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x502yxL0/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much! It gets displayed now

Answer (score 1):

You don't append HTML, but a jQuery node. Like this:

```
$("#gen_div").append($("<div></div>").attr('id', 'well')); //create new div
```

Comment: Oh, you _can_ append HTML :) My bad. It's kind of ugly though.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.html("your html")
```

To fill it with your raw html